# PowerShell - Password Expiration Email

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to edit a PS script that will get a report of AD users whose passwords are expiring in 7 days and send an email to those users. The email gets sent but I'm having a hard time getting the display of the name and email formatted the way I am intending. I will be changing the send to $user.emailaddress. Just testing with my email for now.

Here is the code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 
#Create warning dates for future password expiration
$SevenDayWarnDate = (get-date).adddays(7).ToLongDateString()

#Email Variables
$ExchangeServer = "smtp.company.com"
$FromAddress = "password@company.com"
$myemail = me@company.com
$Subject = "Your password is about to expire"

# Function to create report email
function SendNotification{
 $Msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
 $Smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($ExchangeServer)
 $Msg.From = $FromAddress
 $Msg.To.Add($myemail)
 $Msg.Subject = $Subject
 $Msg.Body = $EmailBody
 $Msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
 $Smtp.Send($Msg)

}
 
#Find accounts that are enabled and have expiring passwords
$users = Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0 } `
 -Properties "Name", "EmailAddress", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select-Object -Property "Name", "EmailAddress", `
 @{Name = "PasswordExpiry"; Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed").tolongdatestring() }}
 
#check password expiration date and send email on match
foreach ($user in $users) {
     if ($user.PasswordExpiry -eq $SevenDayWarnDate) {
         $days = 7
         $EmailBody = @"
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Your account password will expire soon</title>
</head>
<table width=708 align=center border=0>
    <tr><td>Hello, $user.name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This message is to inform you that the password for your account, $user.EmailAddress, will expire in <b>$days</b> days on <b>$SevenDayWarnDate</b>.</td></tr>
</table>
<body>
</body>
</html>

"@
 
SendNotification

     }
    else {}
 }
```

The way it arrives in email is:

> 

Hello, @{Name=John Smith; EmailAddress=johnsmith@company.com; PasswordExpiry=Wednesday, October 25, 2023}.name

This message is to inform you that the password for your account, @{Name=John Smith; EmailAddress=johnsmith@company.com; PasswordExpiry=Wednesday, October 25, 2023}.EmailAddress, will expire in 7 days on Wednesday, October 25, 2023.

> 

I have tried removing the select-object but that just doesn't send me an email at all. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thank you!

Comment: looks like putting it in a here-string(? - the @" thingie) makes it 'unpack' `$user` to its string representation, you can just escape it by writing it as `$($user.name)`.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you!!